# Best way to make 'n' objects with each with unique data contents?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Firstly, you should know that I am incredibly new to programming, so I will love any detailed explanations.

So what I am attempting to make is a program that basically creates people. This includes unique characteristics as such their name, income, job, etc. And since I planned to make a large number of 'people,' I hoped I could merely state how many people I wanted made, and I would get each of them as a object class. To name them I figured I could do 'person1,' 'person2,' and so on. My trouble came when I found out you can't make strings into objects. (Or rather, it is heavily frowned upon.)

After researching I was able to make each person a dictionary, with a key like 'income' and a value like '60000.' However, when it comes to manipulating the data created it seems much better to uses classes and methods instead.

Thank you, and sorry if this is bad or if I am overlooking something.

Edit: I realized I could ask this better, how can I instantiate a large number of persons, or how do I make the needed variables to instantiate? I suck at explaining things...

Comment: You want to make a 'person' class. This 'class' acts as the blueprint for which you can create ('instantiate') x amount of persons, and name each of those person 'instances' as you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are asking two distinct questions (correct me if I'm wrong).  The first - how should you store your data.  The second - how can you do that repeatedly with ease.

There are a couple of ways you can store the data.  I don't know your exact usecase so I can't say exactly which one would work best (you mentioned creating objects in your question so I'll use that for further examples)

Objects

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name, income):
        self.name = name
        self.income = income
```

[Namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> a = namedtuple("person", ['name', 'income'])
>>> a
<class '__main__.person'>
>>> ab = a("Dannnnno", 100)
>>> ab
person(name='Dannnnno', income=100)
>>> ab.name
'Dannnnno'
>>> ab.income
100
```

Dictionaries

```
someperson = {0 : {name:"Dannnno", income:100}}
someotherperson = {1: {name:"kcd", income:100}}
```

---

As for creating large numbers of them - either create a class like `GroupOfPeople` or use a function.

Using the Classes example from above (I assume you could translate the other two examples appropriately)

```
class GroupOfPeople(object):

    def __init__(self, num_people):
        self.people = [Person("Default", 0) for i in range num_people]

####

def MakeLotsOfPeople(num_people):
    return [Person("Default", 0) for i in range num_people]
```

You could then edit those separate `Person` instances to whatever you want.  You could also edit the class/function to accept another input (like a filename perhaps) that stored all of your name/income/etc data.

If you want a dictionary of the group of people just replace the list comprehensions with a dictionary comprehension, like so

```
{i : Person("Default", 0) for i in range num_people}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up Object Oriented Programming. This is the concept you are trying to wrap your head around.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming